# Is this statement about formnovalidate true?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

> A `Boolean` which, if present, specifies that the form-data (inputs) should not be validated when submitted.

Why would you use this?

1. If it's applied to your form it allows your JavaScript to manage all validation.
2. If it's applied to your submit input it can be used to allow users to have the ability to leave the form completion and later on continue where they left off without being forced to fix all the validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this statement about formnovalidate true?
>   A Boolean which, if present, specifies that the form-data (inputs) should not be validated when submitted.

Yes, the statement is true. Basically it's what [the documantation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formnovalidate). It's worth mentioning that this HTML5 attribute can be applied to `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` and it overrides default behaviour of the form which validates all inputs before it is submitted. This default behaviour of the form can also be overriden using another HTML5 attribute - [`novalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate) of `<form>` element.

> If it's applied to your form it allows your JavaScript to manage all validation.

You don't apply attribute `formnovalidate` to a `<form>` element. Attribute `novalidate` is used for this purpose - see above. If you apply `novalidate` to a `<form>` or `formnovalidate` to a `<button>` that caused the form to submit then it effectively disables validation of form's input fields by the browser. You can still use some kind of client-side (JavaScript) validation whether or not browser validation is enabled. Disabling the validation allows the user to submit the form to server where you can also validate the form data by your backend.

> If it's applied to your submit input it can be used to allow users to have the ability to leave the form completion and later on continue where they left off without being forced to fix all the validation errors.

That's true, but note that you still have to somehow store and restore the values of inputs by yourself either using local or server-side storage.

See here how combination of `novalidate` and `formnovalidate` works in real life:

```css
form + form {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="window.alert('submitted'); return false;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>This form validates input on submit</legend>
    <input type="text" name="some-text" placeholder="enter some non-blank text" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save without validation" formnovalidate />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form novalidate onsubmit="window.alert('submitted'); return false;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>This form never validates input on submit</legend>
    <input type="text" name="some-text" placeholder="enter some non-blank text" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save without validation" formnovalidate />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```